# Why is the status bar disabled in BasicActivity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles

I am using a Basic Activity to show some results but the top bar is not visible in this activity like other actives.how can i do it ? Advance thanks for any comment on this

[image]

here is my mainfest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ResultActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>
```

Layout for Activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewDetails"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />
```

Comment: It is probably `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` in your manifest. Try removing it .

Comment: @Jimmy  i tried i am getting this error:  This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: You are using AppTheme in application level. Check your AppTheme defintion, it will be in your styles.xml. You may find something interesting there.

Comment: post your style.xml and also activity code.

Comment: @Jimmy Thanks a lot !  you are right, i was l0oking at style but it was in v21/style  ,i have just commented out this line and status bar is showing now<!--<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>-->   i dont know why it was set to trasparent ..